# Best way to programmatically parse and transform ASP.NET Webform pages?

Tags: asp.net

I need to programmatically parse and transform ASP.NET webform pages. It's a requirement that I have =(.

Anyone know any tools or frameworks?

Update:

I just need to modify ASPX pages (not rendered HTML code).

There are no inline c# code.

Comment: I need more details than that.

Comment: The ASPX page?  or the HTML page that's generated? And transform them into what?

Comment: Not an answer, but a thought that may apply if your circumstances are just right:  I use UserControls a lot because they provide designer support, are parsed by the .NET runtime, and can be created manually with LoadControl().

Comment: Do you need to do something like "find & replace" on all web forms before transforming it to HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are parsing the resulting pages of an ASP.Net webform, meaning just HTML, then I'd go for [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) and using XSLT for the transformation.

If you need to parse the actual .aspx server side code before it's rendered, then please include more information about what you need to do.